# jquery function with Atahualpa (Wordpress theme)

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, jquery

I have one jquery function for mouse movement (see it in action [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv29e/155/)), and I need to get it to work with Atahualpa.

I've put this code in g2.js file, and I've uploaded the file in atahualpa/js folder.

I'm trying to edit functions.php and I've tried 2 basic things:

```
wp_register_script ( 'g2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/g2.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
wp_enqueue_script ( 'g2' );
```

and

```
add_action('g2', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/g2.js');
```

neither one won't work. I'm probably doing something wrong...

Can you please help me with this?

**edit**: I've finally found the complete solution which actually works - see it [**here**](http://gomakethings.com/jquery-wordpress/).

solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the complete solution which actually works - see it [**here**](http://gomakethings.com/jquery-wordpress/).

solved.